# Do I have mistake in script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

```
function printPage(id)   
{
 var html='<html><head><link href="css/styler.css" rel="stylesheet">';
 html+= document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;

 html+='</html>';

 var printWin = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status =0');
 printWin.document.write(html);
 printWin.document.close();
 printWin.focus();
 printWin.print();
 printWin.close();
}
```

Hello, I have this function which prints specific div, I want to link stylesheet to this and I have mistake somewhere. Linking only this stylesheet works, however when i link stylesheet

```
     <link href="css/calender.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

it displays nothing as if were the file not there. The css file is there and I have no idea why this doesn´t work. Anybody sees a mistake ?

http://image.prntscr.com/image/e4615edd03274cc69e48e69172f9e431.png -- my folder

(I´m calling it from directory kalendar)

Only the one css file works every other css file is behaving like it doesnt exist.

Comment: how do you put the new stylesheet in your function?

Comment: In the First row var html=

Answer (score 0):

can you try this instead?

```
function printPage(id)   
{
    var html='<html><head><link href="css/callender.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body>';
    html+= document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;

    html+='</body></html>';

    var printWin = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status =0');
    printWin.document.write(html);
    printWin.document.close();
    printWin.focus();
    printWin.print();
    printWin.close();
}
```

btw your link tag is `calender.css` while your file is `callender.css` (there are 2 `l`s)

Comment: Just a typo its only for example, ill try  your way